# Why is the kubelet slower than docker cli to start a container?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to understand why one of my containers in a pod is slower to start when started by the kubelet, than it is when started via the docker cli directly on the GKE node itself.

Here's the kubelet log. The container is started, and but stays in an unready state for 23 seconds:

```
18:49:55.000 Container image "eu.gcr.io/proj/ns/myimage@sha256:fff668" already present on machine
18:49:55.000 Created container
18:49:56.000 Started container
18:49:56.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:49:58.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:00.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:02.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:04.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:06.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:08.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:10.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:12.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:14.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:16.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
18:50:18.000 Readiness probe failed: cat: /tmp/healthy: No such file or directory
```

Finally the container *actually really* starts 23 seconds later. I know this because the very first thing it does is print the following log line, and then write the /tmp/healthy file for the readinessProbe.

```
18:50:18.000 17:50:18,572|MainThread|INFO|cli|Starting application
```

However, as the following command shows by printing the current date, and then starting the container with the docker cli (on the same node as the kubelet is running on above) it should only take ~1 second to start the container.

```
mark@gke-cluster-3 ~ $ date ++%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N; docker run -it eu.gcr.io/proj/ns/myimage@sha256:fff668
2017-11-25 16:37:01.188799045
2017-11-25 16:37:02,246|MainThread|INFO|cli|Starting application
```

It's driving me a bit nuts! Any thoughts about what could be causing this welcomed :)

Comment: I would certainly think that deploying via “kubectl” could add some overhead since scheduling and other additional processes will have to take place via the Master node. Nevertheless following a simple example like [this one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/docker-cli-to-kubectl/), I am not able to notice any difference.  Do you get any additional information while describing the POD or listing the cluster events?

Comment: Scheduling has already happened by this stage. Notice I am talking about `kubelet` not `kubectl`. I've never noticed it before either in my experience with kubernetes, that's why I'm so perplexed by this particular container.

Comment: Could it be something about your process, combined with Kubernetes environment variables? Do you know why does it take 20 seconds for  `/tmp/healthy` to show up?

Comment: By the way this looks like an isolated case for your image/setup. GKE/Kubernetes does not take this long to start a container. Normally it's comparable to Docker in most cases.

Comment: No, I don't know why it takes 20 seconds for the probe file to be seen after the container starts. That's pretty much the purpose of the question ;). However I *do know* that the first thing that the python script does when it starts is write this file. That's why I'm confused by the time lapse between the kubelet `started container` log and the readiness probe succeeding 23 seconds later.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan do you know if it's possible to put the kubelet logs into debug mode on GKE?

Comment: @MarkNS hmm yeah I bet you can do that, although I haven't done myself. Try having a 1-node cluster, SSH in, find the right kubelet flag (-v=10 ?) edit the systemd unit file for kubelet, systemctl [reload/restart] kubelet.service, see journalctl as sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem with the slow start up of these containers was constrained CPU for the Python interpreter during start up. I added a bash script that would print the datetime before starting the Python process and when varying the CPU resources available to the container, the problem becomes painfully clear.

```
cpu: 10m

2017-12-18 08:05:46,1513584346 starting script
2017-12-18 08:06:22,318|MainThread|INFO|cli|Application startup

cpu: 50m

2017-12-18 08:15:11,1513584911 starting script
2017-12-18 08:15:27,317|MainThread|INFO|cli|Application startup

cpu: 100m

2017-12-18 08:07:46,1513584466 starting script
2017-12-18 08:07:53,218|MainThread|INFO|cli|Application startup

cpu: 150m

2017-12-18 08:18:16,1513585096 starting script
2017-12-18 08:18:20,730|MainThread|INFO|cli|Application startup

cpu: 200m

2017-12-18 08:09:14,1513584554 starting script
2017-12-18 08:09:17,922|MainThread|INFO|cli|Application startup
```

It's a bit frustrating because the applications consume around 10m CPU at run time. I'm going to investigate module imports and other recommendations from here: https://lwn.net/Articles/730915/

Comment: This is a programming QA site, not server related. Off you go to ServerFault.